# Working on this Java program to understand how SMTP works (not allowed to use JavaMail)

Tags: java, sockets, email, smtp

I'm not sure how pass on the encoded base64 credentials onto the mail server. Is there any way to do so without using JavaMail? I keep running into authentication 530 authentication required error and I know this is a result of not sending the credentials correctly, but i'm unable to figure this bit out.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class EmailClient
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
// Establish a TCP connection with the mail server.
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory)
SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).
createSocket(InetAddress.getByName("smtp.gmail.com"), 465);

/* encoding the username and password in Base64 for SMTP */
Encoder base64Encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
String smtpUser = 
base64Encoder.encodeToString("username".getBytes());
String smtpPass = 
base64Encoder.encodeToString("password".getBytes());

 // Create a BufferedReader to read a line at a time.
 InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);


// Read greeting from the server.
String response = br.readLine();
System.out.println(response);
if (!response.startsWith("220")) {
throw new Exception("220 reply not received from server.");
}

// Get a reference to the socket's output stream.
   OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

// Send HELO command and get server response.
   String command = "HELO alice\r\n";
   System.out.print(command);
   os.write(command.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
   response = br.readLine();
   System.out.println(response);
   if (!response.startsWith("250")) {
   throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server.");
        }
// Authentication
   String cmmd authMsg = "AUTH LOGIN\r\n"

// How do I send my encoded credentials to the server?

// Send MAIL FROM command.
   String mailFrom = "MAIL FROM: <xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>\r\n";
   System.out.print(mailFrom);
   os.write(mailFrom.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
   response = br.readLine();
   System.out.println(response);
   if (!response.startsWith("250")) {
   socket.close();
   throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server.");
        }
        // Send RCPT TO command.
        String commandRCPT = "RCPT TO:<xxxxxxxxxx.com>\r\n";
        System.out.print(commandRCPT);
        os.write(commandRCPT.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        response = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);
        if (!response.startsWith("250")) {
        socket.close();
        throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server.");
        }

        // Send DATA command.
        String commandDATA = "DATA\r\n";
        System.out.print(commandDATA);
        os.write(commandDATA.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        response = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);
        if (!response.startsWith("354")) {
        socket.close();
        throw new Exception("354 reply not received from server.");
        }

        // Send message data.
        String msgLine1 = "email sent\r\n";
        System.out.print(msgLine1);
        os.write(msgLine1.getBytes("US-ASCII"));

        // End with line with a single period.
        String msgLine2 = ".\r\n";
        System.out.print(msgLine2);
        os.write(msgLine2.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        response = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);
        if (!response.startsWith("250")) {
        socket.close();
        throw new Exception("250 reply not received from server.");
        }

        // Send QUIT command.
        String commandQUIT = "QUIT\r\n";
        System.out.print(commandQUIT);
        os.write(commandQUIT.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        response = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);
        if (!response.startsWith("221")) {
        socket.close();
        throw new Exception("221 reply not received from server.");
        }

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [SMTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication) taking place in the code you have shown, that is why the `RCPT TO` command is failing.  See [What is the need of SMTP AUTH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205913/).

Your SMTP client needs to send a successful `AUTH` command after connecting to the server, identifying itself, and before sending any `MAIL FROM`/`RCPT TO`/`DATA` commands.  You need to use `EHLO` instead of `HELO` in order to determine which `AUTH` schemes (`LOGIN`, `PLAIN`, `GSSAPI`, `DIGEST-MD5`, `CRAM-MD5`, `OAUTHBEARER`, etc) the server actually supports, and then authenticate accordingly with one of them <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: FYI, `mail.smtp2go.com` supports [`CRAM-MD5`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2195), [`PLAIN`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616), and [`LOGIN`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-murchison-sasl-login-00) auth schemes. See [this reference](https://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm) that describes them in more detail.</sup>

Refer to [RFC 4422: Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4422), [RFC 4954:  SMTP Service Extension for Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954) and other related RFCs for more details.

I also suggest you read [RFC 5321: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) to understand how the SMTP protocol works in general, because the code you have right now is incomplete in how it handles the protocol, in particular in how it reads the server's responses (see [section 4.2: SMTP Replies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2)).

Try something more like this:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EmailClient
{
    private SSLSocket socket;

    private BufferedReader br;
    private OutputStream os;

    private String lastResponseText;

    private void checkReplyCode(int replyCode, int expectedReplyCode)
    {
        if (replyCode != expectedReplyCode)
            throw new Exception(lastResponseText);
    }

    private int checkReplyCodes(int replyCode, int expectedReplyCodes[])
    {
        if (expectedReplyCodes == null)
            return replyCode;

        for (int i = 0; i < expectedReplyCodes.length; ++i)
        {
            if (replyCode == expectedReplyCodes[i])
                return replyCode;
        }

        throw new Exception(lastResponseText);
    }

    private int readResponse()
    {
        lastResponseText = "";

        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        lastResponseText = line;

        if ((line.length() > 3) && (line[3] == '-'))
        {
            String prefix = line.substring(0, 4);
            do
            {
                line = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                lastResponseText += ("\r\n" + line.substring(4));
            }
            while (line.startsWith(prefix));
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(lastResponseText.substring(0, 3));
    }

    private void readResponse(int expectedReplyCode)
    {
        checkReplyCode(readResponse(), expectedReplyCode);
    }

    private int readResponse(int expectedReplyCodes[])
    {
        return checkReplyCodes(readResponse(), expectedReplyCodes);
    }

    private void sendLine(String line)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
        os.write((line + "\r\n").getBytes("US-ASCII"));
    }

    private int sendCommand(String command)
    {
        sendLine(command);
        return readResponse();
    }

    private void sendCommand(String command, int expectedReplyCode)
    {
        sendLine(command);
        readResponse(expectedReplyCode);
    }

    private int sendCommand(String command, int expectedReplyCodes[])
    {
        sendLine(command);
        return readResponse(expectedReplyCodes);
    }

    private String stringAsBase64(String data)
    {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Establish a TCP connection with the mail server.
        socket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(InetAddress.getByName("smtp.gmail.com"), 465);

        // Create a BufferedReader to read a line at a time.
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        // Get a reference to the socket's output stream.
        os = socket.getOutputStream();

        // Read greeting from the server.
        readResponse(220);

        // Send HELO command and get server response.
        //sendCommand("HELO alice", 250);
        sendCommand("EHLO alice", 250);

        // Authentication
        sendCommand("AUTH LOGIN", 334);

        /* encoding the username and password in Base64 for SMTP */
        if (sendCommand(stringAsBase64("username"), new int[]{235, 334}) == 334)
            sendCommand(stringAsBase64("password"), 235);

        // Send MAIL FROM command.
        sendCommand("MAIL FROM: <xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>", 250);

        // Send RCPT TO command.
        sendCommand("RCPT TO:<xxxxxxxxxx.com>", 250);

        // Send DATA command.
        sendCommand("DATA", 354);

        // Send message data.
        sendLine("From: <xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>");
        sendLine("To: <xxxxxxxxxx.com>");
        sendLine("Subject: Test");
        sendLine("");
        sendLine("email sent");

        // End with line with a single period.
        sendCommand(".", 250);

        // Send QUIT command.
        sendCommand("QUIT", 221);

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @CSN17 - *"... but once I'm authenticated how do I run my java program ..."*  It is your Java program that should be sending the AUTH (after the HELO, before other SMTP commands).

Comment: @Stephen I get that now. I was getting confused between using SMTP commands over command line with writing a program that would do the exact same thing, since the task was a bit ambiguously worded. I have now edited my code above to reflect the changes that i've made. However I'm still stuck with the authentication issue and I do not know how to send the base encoded versions of username and password to the server. Any insights?

Comment: There is a class in the Java SE class library for doing base64 encoding.  Look it up.  Also check that the SMTP spec says.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you. I've included the library for base64 encoding and tried to send the credentials after the AUTH LOGIN command, several times but not had any luck with resolving thi, I'm fairly new to Java and I've about done the best I can with this.

Comment: I can't see your attempt at sending the credentials to the server using AUTH LOGIN.  All I see is a comment.  Please show us your attempt at writing it.  Hint: there is an example of AUTH LOGIN in https://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm

Comment: (*"... not had any luck with resolving this ..."*.  Luck has nothing to do with it. There is no point being defeatist about this.   Just keep working.)

Comment: @CSN17 "*I do not know how to send the base encoded versions of username and password to the server*" - really? Did you even read the documents I linked to in my answer? Send `AUTH LOGIN` and check for a 334 reply. Then send the base64 encoded username and check for a 235 or 334 reply. If 334 is received, send the base64 encoded password and check for a 235 reply.

Comment: @CSN17 I have updated my answer with a code example

Comment: @StephenC _"Luck has nothing to do with it. There is no point being defeatist about this. Just keep working"_ I just meant that as a figure of speech really, not an excuse not to put in the work. Either way I appreciate all the assistance that both you and Remy Lebeau have given me and to answer your previous comment the reason I did not include that part of my code was because I was just embarrassed to put really my bad code out there and was hoping someone who knew more than my 60 days of Java could help me out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for the code! I did read the documents you linked but after sending AUTH LOGIN I was not getting any response, just an error, so I knew that my code was incorrect - that is what I meant when I said _I do not know how to send the encoded versions of username and password to the server_. I read the documents you linked, understood the topic better and was able to do it via command line using the SMTP commands, but for me at least that is a far cry away from actually coding something that does the same thing successfully. Thank you again for your time and assistance!